# Merge two audio files(not concat) in Java(API)?

Tags: java, audio

I need to merge two audio files together. Basically place one audio file on top of another and make one file. I have seen some posts on concatenating two audio files, but none on this. Thanks for any help.

Comment: It sounds like what you want is "mixing". There are plenty of questions and answers about this.

Comment: I just ended up calling ffmpeg from java.

Comment: Could you explain in detail how you did it and set is as your answer for us?

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you take a look at [JSyn](http://www.softsynth.com/jsyn/).  I would discourage you to attempt to do it yourself, since it can get complicated with multiple audio formats.  It supports a lot more as well.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. Use jresources.org to help you. You could use their example: http://www.jsresources.org/examples/MixingAudioInputStream.java.html. For the org.tritonus.share.sampled.TConversionTool package, if you have problems using their library, then download their source code (http://sourceforge.net/projects/tritonus/files/): it's open source, and try using it. I tried it and it worked for me :D. I'm grateful for those guys!