# Is there anyway to record sounds(play with SoundPool)?

Tags: android, audio-recording, soundpool

I am developing an application with some buttons in it. When a button touched, the application play a sound with SoundPool method. Is there anyway to record the sequence of sounds that user plays and save it to a file?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, there isn't. But you could take the same data that you have in your SoundPool and write it to a file at the same time as you play it (might require some decoding and encoding on your app's part).

Comment: @Michael
Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 3):

Sure thing, as you already have `OnClickHandlers` on the Buttons, and you call `SoundPool` from there, simply add a line of code that stores the event in some `List`...

Comment: This is possible but when application supports multitouch it seems too complex.

Comment: what's the problem with multitouch? Your `OnClickListener` will be called normally...

Comment: The problem is when user touches two(or more) buttons Simultaneously. I think saving these sounds is complex. isn't it?

Comment: Ah i thought you only want to save the event and not the sound... Well, how about really only saving the event (with timestamp and which sound was played) and later generating the output audio file with some library or tool? Saving the events with multitouch shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Sure. saving the events is a good way but I don't have any idea to make output audio.

Comment: maybe this post will be of any help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12568326/merge-two-audio-filesnot-concat-in-javaapi